# Inserting DATE into Oracle Database with Python

Tags: python, oracle

TABLE in ORACLE....

```sql
SQL> desc mytable2
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 D                                                  DATE
 A                                                  NUMBER
 C                                                  NUMBER
```

DATAFRAME in Pandas has following data

```
date    open    high
..........................
2020-07-07  375.41  378.62
```

I am new to python trying to add this data to the table. TRYING SAMPLE DATA TEST before i add DF data to it. If i use the COMMENTED insert it fails as i am passing the STRING to date column - I am trying to see how to translate the STRING to DATE in python before passing to Oracle -- Please advise.

```py
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd

connect=cx_Oracle.connect('astro/astro@10.0.0.145:1621/analytica')
cursor=connect.cursor()

#cursor.execute(" insert into TTTT values (:1, :2, :3, :4, :5, :6)", ['2020-10-10', 12,12,12,12,12]
cursor.execute("insert into MyTable2 values (:D, :A, :B)" , [(to_date('2020-12-12','yyyy-mm-dd' ) ,15, 15])
connect.commit()
```

Comment: http://www.sqlines.com/oracle-to-sql-server/to_date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind values can only contain data, so including the SQL "to_date()" function won't work. The basic solution is to use something like this:

```
cursor.execute("insert into MyTable2 values (to_date(:D,'YYYY-MM-DD'), :A, :B)" , ['2020-12-12' ,15, 15]
```

You could alternatively set your default date format, or just insert a date instead of the string representation of a date.

You may find useful info in the [cx_Oracle documentation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).